# Repeated calls to glVertexPointer and glDraw

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm using OpenGL ES on Android to draw some shapes, so I have some Model classes to load the vertices etc from an .obj file.

Each model then has a onDrawFrame() method which is called by the Renderer to place it in the scene.

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
    gl.glVertexPointer(0, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVerts);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, mFaces.capacity(), GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mFaces);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

My confusion now is where to "reset" the vertex pointer (I think), because if I try to create an arbitrary line from a new glVertexPointer using 2 new verts, and a call to glDrawElements(GL_LINES) using those id's, the line always seems to use verts 0 and 1 from the original data.

Do I need to pre-define all my scene's verts in one master glVertexPointer tracked by the master scene somehow, and have each model just call glDrawElements with a suitable offset?  Or do I clear the pointer somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will solve your problem but your glVertexPointer line should look like this:

```
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVerts);
```

Since there are 3 coordinates per vertex.  Besides that you should just be able to set a new pointer using your method above.

Comment: Hmm, okay thanks.  It must be something borked in the rest of my model class hierarchy then. (The glVertexPointer line is buried a little deeper in my class hierarchy, so is correct in the running code)
I'll run up some tests and try and narrow it down.

Comment: Yea, are you doing any texturing or color assignments?  You should have all of that code together in the onDrawFrame to make it easier to maintain a consistent state, I have definitely run into problems where I have forgotten to disable/enable pointers.